# what is the reason in java when i draw image with large size it cause slowness?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

i had problem with slow when i tried to draw an image with scale : 1280*768 and it's format is PNG and it's size is 3.26 MB nearly , but when i converted it to JPEG , it's size be 226KB , ! and the slownes problem disappeared !! ,

my question is why slowness occured while trying to draw an buffered image with large size ? is java handle small size of images only or what ?

Comment: One doesn't "draw" PNGs or JPEGs (those are only serialized formats for the image). However, the image could possibly be being loaded slightly differently (or at different speeds: I would expect the much larger PNG to take longer to load than the much smaller JPG, but the actual image drawing speed should be the same barring some other internal fun like a buffer in a non-blt'able format). Have an example test-case for the "slow" and "not-slow" scenarios?

Comment: If you mean that you shrunk the image dimensions when you converted it to JPEG, annotate that as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you shrink an image to JPEG, you lose some of the image data, making the file shorter.

It takes less time to read a shorter file.
And `3.26 MB > 226 KB`!

You might not see a difference on your screen because the original file is so large, that not every pixel might be shown, but there is a loss of quality when converting to JPEG.

Check out this site about image file formats: [GIF's, PNG's, or JPEG's?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30941/whats-the-difference-between-jpg-png-and-gif/)

**EDIT** You can also look at this website on image drawing: http://www.kitfox.com/javaOne2007/javaOne-notes.pdf

You can render images quickly using [java.awt.RenderingHints.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) Using this with BufferedImageOp can make your images load faster (at the expense of some quality, though).

I hope this helped!

Comment: For me it is true that PNG is a loss-less image format whereas JPG is a lossy image format. Hence, it is a litte bit "slower" to "load" a PNG file compared to a JPG file on its first instance due to its size (for the same 821x672 image res, it takes about 1040KB for PNG and just 396KB for JPG; a big difference here). It will be much slower if the PNG file has an alpha channel. There are a few techniques to speed up image loading like image slicing and image sub-sampling of an image file into a `BufferedImage` or other image data buffer

Comment: yes i know that quality of jpeg image will be less than quality of png image , and at the same time i need high quality image !! , so is there any method to speed drawing of png images by java ? or if there methods to decrease size of png images qithout lossses of quality ?